# Click Function in JQuery

Tags: jquery

$("#displayPanel #save #saveForm").live("click", function(){

```
                   //Move to forms/homepage
    });
```

What I'm trying is when clicking on the `saveForm` Button I want to move to a URL(homepage) Where ii had some list of saved forms.

I'm new to JQuery.
Note:

```
       Where my saveForm is like
       <input id='saveForm' type='Submit' value='Save Form'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean redirect to page?

document.location = 'http://yourpage';

Comment: Ya i want to redirect to homepage

Comment: well, if you want use ajax in proper way you should use json, for example. 

$('#object').click(function() {
  $.post('http://yourpage/blabla/', params, function(resp) {
    if (resp.result == 'ok') {
      document.location = 'http://some_other_place_to_go';
    } else alert('Some error');
  }
}

Comment: document.location should be avoided. It doesn't work on all browsers

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use **document.location**. It has been replaced by **window.location**.

From the Mozilla docs:

> document.location was originally a
>   read-only property, although Gecko
>   browsers allow you to assign to it as
>   well. For cross-browser safety, use
>   window.location instead.

The only cross-browser way to navigate to a new URL from javascript is:

```
window.location = "http://mysite.com/url";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the location using javascript by:

```
document.location = 'http://google.com';
```

But why are you doing it this way? In this scenario it is usually much simpler to POST the page, and redirect at the server side. You don't really need JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, if you want to change the page, just use `document.location`. I do have a few other tips for you though:

---

```
$('#displayPanel #save #saveForm')
```

This is unnecessary and slower to run. Just change it to `$('#saveForm')` and the query will only need to do one lookup.

```
.live('click', ...
```

Given how specific your selector is, I'd suggest that using `live` is also unnecessary. `live` is meant to be used to apply events to large numbers of elements which may be added to the DOM at any point after the binding. Since you've only got one element with the id `saveForm`, just apply a click handler to that element normally.

Though, all that said, if all you want is your button to post the form and take the user to the homepage, you don't need any javascript or jQuery, just plain HTML.

```
<form method="post" action="homepage.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to homepage" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just a small addition: the reason why nickf says your query is unnecessary is that you look for an element with the "saveForm" ID. In HTML we ID's need to be unique, so there can not be more than one "saveForm" element. $("#XXXXX") should always return always one item. Your query looks first for the element displayPanel, then it looks in its children for the element save, and then for saveForm.